# Retrieve parameter from url

Tags: session

Given a certain url, custom = [www.namesite.com/r=namerefferrer](http://www.namesite.com/r=namerefferrer)

to initialize a `$_SESSION` and retrieve the value of this `$_SESSION` I did:

I set this in functions.php:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
    if($_GET['r']){
        $_SESSION['referrer']=$_GET['r'];
    }
}
```

in my front-page.php;

```
<?php 
$rp = $_SESSION['referrer'];
echo $rp;
?>
```

but it does not recover anything unless I modify the url by adding a? after the /, like this:

[www.namesite.com/?r=namerefferrer](http://www.namesite.com/?r=namerefferrer)

how to recover the session and show it without `?`

Comment: You need the `r`, that's how get parameters work. Also note that PHP sessions don't work on a lot of WordPress hosts, and there are scaling and security consequences. Since PHP Sessions stores a small cookie with the session ID, you should just use cookies instead or URL parameters

Comment: @TomJNowell on the host where wp is installed, the sessions work correctly, there are no security problems because it is an end in itself session, which is only used for netowrk marketing, given a custom link to a user, I want to record only the conversion taken the code is put in a cf7, so zero problems

Comment: Would it not make more sense to do it in Javascript then? By doing it in PHP with sessions caching that page is impossible, but with javascript you sidestep the problem entirely and can just read directly from the URL with no cookies or sessions at all